# How to keep React component state between mount/unmount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple component `<StatefulView>` that maintains an internal state. I have another component `<App>` that toggles whether or not `<StatefulView>` is rendered.

However, I want to keep `<StatefulView>`'s internal state between mounting/unmouting.

I figured I could instantiate the component in `<App>` and then control whether its rendered/mounted.

```
var StatefulView = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  inc: function() {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count+1})
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.inc}>inc</button>
          <div>count:{this.state.count}</div>
        </div>
    )
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      show: true,
      component: <StatefulView/>
    }
  },
  toggle: function() {
    this.setState({show: !this.state.show})
  },
  render: function() {
    var content = this.state.show ? this.state.component : false
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggle}>toggle</button>
        {content}
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

This apparently doesnt work and a new `<StatefulView>` is created on each toggle.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccorcos/xd4wkutw/).

Is there a way to hang on to the same component after it is unmounted so it can be re-mounted?

Comment: you could store the state on a Store using Flux

Comment: yeah, I was trying not to have save/load methods. Also, this could get tricky for me. Think about this in the context of a UINavigationController -- I may have multiple of the same exact component, but with different states, at different levels in the navigation stack...

Answer (score 79):

Since you can't keep the state in the component itself when it unmounts, you have to decide where else it should be saved.

Consider these options:

1. **React state in parent**: If a parent component remains mounted, maybe it should be the owner of the state or could provide an initial state to an uncontrolled component below. You can pass the value back up before the component unmounts. With React context you can hoist the state to the very top of your app (see e.g. [unstated](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated-next)).
2. **Outside of React**: E.g. [use-local-storage-state](https://github.com/astoilkov/use-local-storage-state). Note that you might need to manually reset the state in between tests. Other options are query params in the URL, state management libraries like MobX or Redux, etc.

---

If you're looking for an easy solution where the data is persisted outside of React, this Hook might come in handy:

```
const memoryState = {};

function useMemoryState(key, initialState) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
    const hasMemoryValue = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(memoryState, key);
    if (hasMemoryValue) {
      return memoryState[key]
    } else {
      return typeof initialState === 'function' ? initialState() : initialState;
    }
  });

  function onChange(nextState) {
    memoryState[key] = nextState;
    setState(nextState);
  }

  return [state, onChange];
}
```

Usage:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useMemoryState('todos', ['Buy milk']);
```

Comment: Just a warning to others this is not going to work with testing or Components that get used in more than one spot.

Comment: @pllee not necessarily - if you're using meaningful IDs.

For instance - the component using state could generate its ID on mount, like GUID.

Then you'd call this function like:

const [todos, setTodos] = useMemoryState('guid-here', ['Buy milk']);

And possibly, for different variables, this could be extended to:

const [todos, setTodos] = useMemoryState('guid-here', 'todos', ['Buy milk']);
const [numbers, setNumbers] = useMemoryState('guid-here', 'numbers', [1, 42]);

Answer (score 34):

OK. So after talking with a bunch of people, it turns out that there is no way to save an instance of a component. Thus, we HAVE to save it elsewhere.

1) The most obvious place to save the state is within the parent component.

This isn't an option for me because I'm trying to push and pop views from a UINavigationController-like object.

2) You can save the state elsewhere, like a Flux store, or in some global object.

This also isn't the best option for me because it would be a nightmare keeping track of which data belongs to which view in which Navigation controller, etc.

3) Pass a mutable object to save and restore the state from.

This was a suggestion I found while commenting in various issue tickets on React's Github repo. This seems to be the way to go for me because I can create a mutable object and pass it as props, then re-render the same object with the same mutable prop.

I've actually modified it a little to be more generalized and I'm using functions instead of mutable objects. I think this is more sane -- immutable data is always preferable to me. Here's what I'm doing:

```
function createInstance() {
  var func = null;
  return {
    save: function(f) {
      func = f;
    },
    restore: function(context) {
      func && func(context);
    }
  }
}
```

Now in `getInitialState` I'm creating a new instance for the component:

```
component: <StatefulView instance={createInstance()}/>
```

Then in the `StatefulView` I just need to save and restore in `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount`.

```
componentWillMount: function() {
  this.props.instance.restore(this)
},
componentWillUnmount: function() {
  var state = this.state
  this.props.instance.save(function(ctx){
    ctx.setState(state)
  })
}
```

And that's it. It works really well for me. Now I can treat the components as if they're instances :)

Comment: This looks exactly like something I would need. Could you elaborate a bit more? Give an example of storing the state of component and restoring it in real life?

Comment: This is a great fix, Thanks

Answer (score 19):

For those who are just reading this in 2019 or beyond, a lot of details have already been given in the other answers, but there are a couple of things that I want to emphasize here:

- Saving state in some store (Redux) or Context is probably the best
  solution.
- Storing in global variable will only work if there is ever only ONE instance of your component at a time. (How will each instance know which stored state is theirs?)
- Saving in localStorage has just the same caveats as global variable, and since we're not talking about restoring state on browser refresh, it doesn't seem to add any benefit.

Comment: I had the same situation, I didn't go for persist library just because I wanted a common pattern  which should happen even if the users are different. Just use redux

Comment: all of them are equivalent and share the same issues. Storing state in Redux still does not solve the problem of the instance

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 12):

Hmm, you could use `localStorage`, or `AsyncStorage` if React Native.

**React Web**

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  localStorage.setItem('someSavedState', JSON.stringify(this.state))
}
```

Then later that day or 2 seconds later:

```
componentWillMount() {
  const rehydrate = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('someSavedState'))
  this.setState(rehydrate)
}
```

**React Native**

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'

async componentWillMount() {
  try {
    const result = await AsyncStorage.setItem('someSavedState', JSON.stringify(this.state))
    return result
  } catch (e) {
    return null
  }
}
```

Then later that day or 2 seconds later:

```
async componentWillMount() {
  try {
    const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('someSavedState')
    const rehydrate = JSON.parse(data)
    return this.setState(rehydrate)
  } catch (e) {
    return null
  }
}
```

You could also use `Redux` and pass the data into the child component when it renders. You might benefit from researching `serializing` state and the second parameter of the Redux `createStore` function which is for rehydrating an initial state.

Just note that `JSON.stringify()` is an expensive operation, so you should not do it on keypress, etc. If you have concern, investigate debouncing.

Comment: localStorage is interesting concept for web, will give it a go. Thanks

Comment: localStorage is secure. You can store up to about 15 MB of data in it, depending on browser, etc. It works very well for short term persistent data.

Comment: How about performance? Does it take time to read/write local storage compared to mutating global state of react app? muting state potentially rerender a whole lot of components which is why I am also looking for a solution to save a single components state between unmount/mount. But only in a performant way.

Comment: I would say performance is the secondary main concern after just getting the data to persist through dismounts. Storing data in upstream components is basically "lifting state" in React. This is more performant than saving data to disk because you are changing the reference to the data in-memory and basically avoiding garbage collection, so read/write speed will be turbo; however, storing the data in localStorage allows the data to persist as the root component itself is unmounted and remounted.

Comment: `componentWillMount` is deprecating so replace with `componentDidMount` :)

Answer (score 8):

An easy way of caching state between renders would be to use the fact that modules exported form closure over the file that you are working in.

Using a `useEffect` hook you can specify logic that happens on component dismount (i.e. update a variable that is closed over at the module level). This works because imported modules are cached, meaning that the closure created on import never disappears. I'm not sure if this is a GOOD approach or not, but works in cases where a file is only imported once (otherwise the `cachedState` would be shared across all instances of the default rendered component)

```
var cachedState

export default () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(cachedState || {})

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => cachedState = state
  })

  return (...)
}
```

Comment: If going this way, you can actually make use of `useId` by creating a mini "store" -> `const cachedState = new Map<string, unknown>()`, then use `const id = useId()`, then get state by `cachedState.get(id, state)` and set by `cachedState.set(id, state)`. so a cached state is not shared between multiple instances but have their own.

Answer (score 4):

I'm late to the party but if you're using Redux. You'll get that behaviour almost out of the box with redux-persist. Just add its `autoRehydrate` to the store then it will be listening to `REHYDRATE` actions that will automatically restore previous state of the component (from web storage).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert in React but particularly your case could be solved very cleanly without any mutable objects.

```
var StatefulView = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  inc: function() {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count+1})
  },
  render: function() {
      return !this.props.show ? null : (
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.inc}>inc</button>
          <div>count:{this.state.count}</div>
        </div>
    )

  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      show: true,
      component: StatefulView
    }
  },
  toggle: function() {
    this.setState({show: !this.state.show})
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggle}>toggle</button>
        <this.state.component show={this.state.show}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

You can see it at [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mg8605y0/).

Answer (score 2):

I've made a simple NPM package exactly for this purpose. You can find it here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-component-state-cache

Usage is simple. First, include the component somewhere high up in your component tree, like this

```
import React from 'react'
import {ComponentStateCache} from 'react-component-state-cache'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux' // for example
import MyApp from './MyApp.js'

class AppWrapper extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={this.store}>
                <ComponentStateCache>
                    <MyApp />
                </ComponentStateCache>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

then, you can use it in any of your components as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import { withComponentStateCache } from 'react-component-state-cache'

class X extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            // anything, really.
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Restore the component state as it was stored for key '35' in section 'lesson'
        //
        // You can choose 'section' and 'key' freely, of course.
        this.setState(this.props.componentstate.get('lesson', 35))
    }

    componentDidUnmount() {
         // store this state's component in section 'lesson' with key '35'
        this.props.componentstate.set('lesson', 35, this.state)
    }

}

export default withComponentStateCache(X)
```

That's it. Easy peasy.

Comment: This isn't open source?

Comment: I mean, I made it myself, and released it as open source, so it is!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to unmount and mount while maintaining state, you will need to store the count in `App` and pass down the count via props.

(When doing this, you should be calling a toggle function inside of `App`, you want the functionality which changes data to live with the data).

I will modify your fiddle to be functional and update my answer with it.

Comment: yeah, thats not what I'm getting at though. This is a contrived example so what you mention would work for *this* example, but not for the more complicated issue I'm trying to solve...

Comment: Your question was about maintaining the component specifically.  As far as I know the best you can do is maintain the component's state and re-instantiate the component.

Comment: I see. Thats as far as I know as well. The less contrived version is this: I'm trying to build UITabBarController and UINavigationController equivalents for the web. With the UINavigationController specifically, we can be pushing arbitrary views to the stack and popping them off. Its not really feasible to keep track of all that arbitrary state so it would be great if I could keep the state within the component itself between mounting...

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post looking for a way to build the component state over time, i.e., with each additional page from the backend.

I use a persistor and redux.  However, for this state I wanted to keep it local to the component.  What ended up working: `useRef`.  I'm a bit surprised no one mentioned it so I could be missing an important part of the question.  Notwithstanding, the `ref` persists between renders of React's virtual DOM.

With that in place, I can build my cache over-time, watch the component update (aka re-render), but not worry about "throwing-out" previous api data that remains relevant for the component.

```
  const cacheRef = useRef([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(() => 0);

  // this could be part of the `useEffect` hook instead as I have here
  const getMoreData = useCallback(
    async (pageProp, limit = 15) => {

      const newData = await getData({
        sources,
        page: pageProp,
        limit,
      });

      cacheRef.current = [...(cacheRef.current || []), ...newData];
      
    },
    [page, sources],
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const atCacheCapacity = cacheRef.current.length >= MAX;
    if (!atCacheCapacity) {
      getMoreData(page + 1);
      setPage(page + 1);
    }
  }, [MAX, getMoreData, page]);
```

The component is tricked into re-rendering by tracking a local state that changes with the increasing size of the cache.  I don't copy the ref data on the DOM into the component's local state, just some sort of summary e.g., length.

Comment: i tried your ref solution, but it didn't work, it lost ref values once i am out of the component and came back to component again!

Comment: The use ref saves the data on a node in the DOM.  Is it possible that you are reloading the DOM?

Comment: Re-rendering and re-mounting is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

This won't suffice for the scenario of the thread opener, but maybe for other people stumbling on this thread: Depending on how much persistence you need and how complex the data is you want to store, a query parameter might also suffice.

For example, if you just want to keep a bool `hideItems` between window resizing operations, it will retain if you append it in the manner of `my.example.com/myPage?hideItems=true`. You've got to evaluate the parameter on rendering inside you page/component, e.g. with `NextJS` it would be

```js
const router = useRouter()
const hide = router.query.hideItems
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I select items to payment and save it to state in redux store, when my component is unmout, I want to set state to new list. But I have a special case after I payment success and redirect to another page, I don't want to keep my old data, I use `useRef` like this

```js
const isPayment = useRef(false)

useEffect(() => { 

return () => {
  if(!isPayment.current){
     //if my handlePayment is called, 
     // I won't run my handle when component is unmout 
    Your action when component is unmout
  }
}
},[])

const handlePayment = () => {
  isPayment.current = true

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```