# Component loses state on re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need some help with `React`. As far as I know, it should be working just fine. But, it is not working. What I am trying to do is :

- I have a list of todo.
- You can add new todo and you can also expand the todo section.
- When you expand the todo section, it will open up full screen.

**The problem is, newly added todos are not showing up when you expand the todo. Why is that?** I am basically using the same component. Why is it that the newly added todos dissapeared when todo section is expanded? And vice-versa, when you expand, add new todo and close the modal, newly added todos are not showing up. How can I make new todo persists regardless of the todo section is expanded or not.

Please, take a look at the small demo app I built.

full codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-butterfly-650w8d?file=/src/Demo.jsx)

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the body of the question, an external link can change and make the question either un-answerable in the short term, or unhelpful to later readers in the long term.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep React component state between mount/unmount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352261/how-to-keep-react-component-state-between-mount-unmount)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Todo` component is not getting re-rendered, but unmounted and remounted. You have your state inside the `Todo` component, but each time `expand` changes, `Todo` gets unmounted and remounted inside the `Dialog` component. This causes it to lose its internal state. The solution would be to lift the state up in the tree, i.e., to keep the state inside `Demo` component.

Relevant section in docs: [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there any way to handle this without lifting the state up one level?? Unfortunately, I can't do that in my real app. Is there any other workarounds??

Comment: To be honest, no. The component *needs* to unmount and remount as the parent node (`Dialog` & div) is being changed. You cannot detach and reattach a node to another parent keeping its internal state intact. Every instance of `todoComponent` has its own internal state. You should reconsider state handling in your real app.

Answer (score 1):

You're state gets lost in case it is not managed globally or a layer above. To solve that you could take a look at Redux. It's a library for managing and centralizing application state. It is open-source, well adopted, a good library to know and can also be used for further javascript frameworks like Angular.

https://react-redux.js.org/